# Javascript: Operation not supported

Tags: firefox, javascript

Столкнулся с такой проблемой при написании:

```
    Operation is not supported
    [Прерывать на этой ошибке]  
    return "true" === sessionStorage.getItem("introWatched")
    ctp3.js (строка 22)
```

Firefox 11 не поддерживает sessionStorage? Быть такого не может.

Comment: Сколько там знаков равенства в операции? Три?

Comment: @alexlz бывает и такое. называется строго равно.

Comment: Если эквивалентны и имеют одинаковый тип.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SessionStorage` не работает локально. Необходимо залить на сервер.

Comment: Благодарю Вас, решение оказалось простым